# What is the first step in creating a SQL Database with my WAMP server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, wamp

I am completely new to WAMP and SQL Databases, but I was wondering about how to connect the two or if it is anything like that, I have looked around and have not got a good explanation. Also, how do I implement this to my VB Window Form application in Visual Studios? - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the wamp server on the browser type localhost and it will open the wampserver  page there on the bottom left side you will see an option of phpmyadmin click on that, it will open the mysql database just enter your id and password and it will open and there you can make database by choosing the option of create new database

Comment: Ahh right, thanks. But how do I implement this with my Visual Basics project?

Comment: Thats a totally different question. Maybe you should read [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html](Download MySQL for Visual Studio) Maybe you dont even need WAMP at all.

Comment: I think you should use ms sql server instead of mysql in visual basic projects because mysql is more efficient with opensource projects.